# xmlunit: Error with ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

So I have the following input, expected output and actual output xml:

**input.xml**

```
<Request>
  <EmailSubjectLine>Main Contact &amp; No Reported To</EmailSubjectLine>
  <ProductRq>
      <Signon>
        <ClientDt>1/6/2017 11:25:45 AM</ClientDt>
        <CustLangPref>en-US</CustLangPref>
      </Signon>
      <SvcRq>
          <RqUID>xxxxxxxx-2802-xxxx-xxxx-bf8361xxxxxx</RqUID>
          <NotificationRq>
              <TransactionRequestDt>2017-01-06</TransactionRequestDt>
              <Currency>USD</Currency>
          </NotificationRq>
      </SvcRq>
  </ProductRq>
<!-- rest of input -->
</Request>
```

**expected-output.xml**

```
<ProductRq xmlns="http://test.org/standards/intake">
    <Audit>
        <TransID>Test</TransID>
    </Audit>
    <Signon>
        <ClientDt>1/6/2017 11:25:45 AM</ClientDt>
        <CustLangPref>en-US</CustLangPref>
    </Signon>
    <SvcRq>
        <RqUID>xxxxxxxx-2802-xxxx-xxxx-bf8361xxxxxx</RqUID>
        <NotificationRq>
            <RqUID>Test</RqUID>
            <TransactionRequestDt>2017-01-06</TransactionRequestDt>
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
        </NotificationRq>
    </SvcRq>
    <!-- rest of expected-output -->
</ProductRq>
```

**actual-output.xml**

```
<ProductRq xmlns="http://test.org/standards/intake">
    <Audit>
        <TransID>123534Abwe-asdcv-1258qw-asd</TransID>
    </Audit>
    <Signon>
        <ClientDt>1/6/2017 11:25:45 AM</ClientDt>
        <CustLangPref>en-US</CustLangPref>
    </Signon>
    <SvcRq>
        <RqUID>xxxxxxxx-2802-xxxx-xxxx-bf8361xxxxxx</RqUID>
        <NotificationRq>
            <RqUID>CG-17Dawe-12354-Hw35Sf</RqUID>
            <TransactionRequestDt>2017-01-06</TransactionRequestDt>
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
        </NotificationRq>
    </SvcRq>
    <!-- rest of actual-output -->
</ProductRq>
```

I'm comparing them with the following Diff set up:

**MyTest.java**

```
        Diff diff = DiffBuilder
                .compare(xmlExpectedOutput)
                .withTest(xmlOutput)
                .normalizeWhitespace()
                .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
                        .whenElementIsNamed("Audit")
                        .thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./TransID", ElementSelectors.byName))
                        .whenElementIsNamed("NotificationRq")
                        .thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./RqUID", ElementSelectors.byName))
                        .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText)
                        .build()
                        ))
                .checkForSimilar()
                .build();
```

I get the following differences when I run the above input and compare with expected-output.xml:

`[Expected child '{http://test.org/standards/intake}RqUID' but was 'null' - comparing <RqUID...> at /ProductRq[1]/SvcRq[1]/NotificationRq[1]/RqUID[1] to <NULL> (DIFFERENT), Expected child 'null' but was '{http://test.org/standards/intake}RqUID' - comparing <NULL> to <RqUID...> at /ProductRq[1]/SvcRq[1]/NotificationRq[1]/RqUID[1] (DIFFERENT)]`

I don't get why my Element selector wouldn't work, am I using it incorrectly? My aim is whenever TransmissionId or NotificationRq/RqUID are found, to match them with the expected output versions by name only, otherwise use name and text for other elements as these elements contain unique generated ids that change every test run and can't be predicted(with a view to creating a more complex selector later, e.g. to compare ProductRq via name and attribute as a namespace is added to this). Is there  something I'm missing, and am I able to combine the 2 XPath selectors together rather than several when/then lines and the default case?

Note: the xml is transformed via xslt. The namespace on PRoductRq is not there on the source document; the source is copied, the namespace added to ProductRq and then sent for output along with some element removals/modifications/additions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLUnit says the `RqUID` elements inside the `NotificationRq` wouldn't match and of course they are different.

```
.whenElementIsNamed("NotificationRq")
.thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./RqUID", ElementSelectors.byName))
```

means: when XMLUnit tries to find a partner for an `NotificationRq` element then it has to search for an `NotificationRq` that has an `RqUID` child - and only use the `RqUID` element.

It doesn't set up any rules for any other element, in particular `RqUID` itself. For `RqUID` elements the default rules apply and

```
.elseUse(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText)
```

says: XMLUnit only accepts two elements as pairs if their names and the nested text match. Which is not the case for the `RqUID` elements in question.

Your whole `ElementSelector` says

- match `Audit`s if they have `TransID` children of arbitrary content.
- match `NotificationRq`s if they have `RqUID` of arbitrary content.
- use element name and nested text otherwise

which doesn't fit your example. Looking at your XML you probably wanted

- match almost everything by element name and nested text (although from the example the element name would be enough)
- ignore the nested text of `TransId` children of `Audit`s
- ignore the nested text of `RqUID` children of `NotificationRq`

There is no built-in predicate for "element named `foo` if it is a child of an element named `bar`", it could be something like

```
Predicate<Element> transIdInAudit = e -> {
     if (e == null || e.getParentNode() == null) {
         return false;
     }
     return "TransID".equals(e.getLocalName()) && "Audit".equals(e.getParentNode().getLocalName());
};
```

which you likely want to make generalizable :-)

With that you'd use

```
.withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .when(transIdInAudit)
    .thenUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
    .when(rqUIDInNotificationRq) // similar to transIdInAudit
    .thenUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText)
    .build())
```

Maybe you really want to match `SvcRq` if they have matching `RqUID`, maybe not. If so you'd use the structure you currently use for `NotificationRq`.

This in itself will not be enough to ignore the nested text of the matched `TransId` and `RqUID` elements, it will only ensure XMLUnit will pick the nodes you want it to use. For the nested text you'll need a `DifferenceEvaluator`.

Given that you are using `ElementSelectors.byNameAndText` by default, you know the nested texts are the same for all matched nodes except for the two specific elements where you want to ignore the content. So a `DifferenceEvaluator` like

```
DifferenceEvaluators.chain(DifferenceEvaluators.Default,
    DifferenceEvaluators.downgradeDifferencesToEqual(ComparisonType.TEXT_VALUE))
```

should work.

Comment: great explanation, I think I was misinterpreting the byXPath element selector, I thought it was along the lines of if the element is named this, then match this child with the provided selector, not that it must only use the RqUID with the default rules. I eventually happened upon a solution by implementing 2 DifferenceEvaluators but this is much cleaner